# Просмотр каталога на странице

Tags: php, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть генерируемые кодом страницы, которые кладутся в папку на сервере. Как реализовать на php чтобы вот каталог в котором эти куча страниц лежат, можнно было вывести на нужную мне страницу, и чтоб они выводились например по 16 штук, и в низу было вперед назад, и страницы 1 2 3.

Comment: То есть у Вас в папке хранятся  файлы .html и нужно их показать на одной странице   с сортировкой и пагинацией?

Comment: @koks_rs Такое возможно реализовать?

Comment: Используйте readdir и простейшую пагинацию через выделение части массива.

Comment: @ilyaplot Можете написать простенький пример, я php только начал изучать.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php Вот тут есть пример

Comment: @ilyaplot я не совсем понимаю как его использовать в моем случае(

Comment: Я дал ссылку на документацию, в документации есть пример. Больше ничем помочь не могу.